# What is a transformation that can't have shearing called?

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation

What is a transformation called when it can have separate scaling for x and y, rotation, and translation, but it cannot have shearing or scaling AFTER rotation?

Basically if this transformation is applied to a axis aligned rectangle it will always remain a rectangle.  It might be have different dimensions, angle, and location, but it will still have 4 right angles.  Is there a name for a transformation with these constraints?

Comment: Since the set isn't closed under composition (as you say, you can't do unequal scaling after rotation; your claim about "rectangles mapping to rectangles" is true only for _axis-aligned_ rectangles), it's conceivable these mappings have never attracted "serious" attention. Anyway, I've never seen a name given to them, but if it matters, you're looking at affine mappings whose linear part is a $2\times 2$ real matrix of the form $OD$, with $O$ orthogonal and $D$ (invertible and) diagonal.

Comment: @user86418, his language is ambiguous, but if **every** rectangle goes to a rectangle, the linear part is conformal.

Comment: @WillJagy: Entirely agreed if the OP did mean "preserve arbitrary rectangles", though the wording "cannot have shearing or scaling after rotation" still suggests to me the OP meant "axis-aligned". :)

Comment: @user86418, good thinking, i did not know what to make of that. I checked his questions on StackOverflow (through his "Accounts", hard to tell mathematics background, mixed. i showed a non-axis-aligned example in answer, maybe that will lead to a clarification of the question.

Comment: thank you user86418.  That is what I meant.  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If terminology were consistent, the thing you ask for would be called an [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis) transformation, and the things which are actually called [orthogonal transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation) would better be called [orthonormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) transformations.

But since terminology is as inconsistent as it is, I believe the best you can do is stating that your transformation matrix is made from [orthogonal vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Euclidean_vector_spaces), forms an [orthogonal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_basis), or that your transformation maps the unit vectors to pairwise orthogonal vectors.